# Rsync Nexcloud data folder - ownership

Tags: permissions, rsync, ownership, nextcloud

My Nextcloud data folder is on a Ubuntu Server 16.04 NUC and I have a Raspberry Pi that I use only to backup my entire Nextcloud data folder.

To do this, from the Nexctloud server, I run

```
sudo rsync -aAxvH /nextcloud/data/folder pi@192.168.x.x:/media/backups --delete
```

and everything works like a charm. The only question I have is that on the Nexctloud server, the ownership of the files is `www-data:www-data` and once transfered, it becomes `pi:pi`.

Is this OK or should I make sure that `www-data` stays the owner once backed up? My goal here is to create a daily backup that would be easy to restore in case of data loss.

On the source files,

> ls -n

gives

```
total 44
drwxr-xr-x  2 33 33 28672 Mar 17 22:44 cache
drwxr-xr-x 20 33 33  4096 Jul 23 14:23 files
drwxr-xr-x  5 33 33  4096 Dec 23  2017 files_trashbin
drwxr-xr-x  5 33 33  4096 Jul 11 15:04 files_versions
drwxr-xr-x  2 33 33  4096 Jul 11 15:05 uploads
```

whereas on the backup it gives

```
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  2 1000 1000 4096 Mar 17 22:44 cache
drwxr-xr-x 20 1000 1000 4096 Jul 23 14:23 files
drwxr-xr-x  5 1000 1000 4096 Dec 23  2017 files_trashbin
drwxr-xr-x  5 1000 1000 4096 Jul 11 15:04 files_versions
drwxr-xr-x  2 1000 1000 4096 Jul 11 15:05 uploads
```

On the source (Nextcloud server), I have

```
edwin@nuc:~$ getent passwd 33
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin
edwin@nuc:~$ getent passwd 1000
edwin:x:1000:1000:Edwin,,,:/home/edwin:/bin/bash
```

While on the Raspberry (backup server), I have

```
pi@pi:/ $ getent passwd 33
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin
pi@pi:/ $ getent passwd 1000
pi:x:1000:1000:,,,:/home/pi:/bin/bash
```

Comment: Can you please add the output of `ls -n FILE...` on both the source and the destination system where `FILE` is an example of a file with differing owner (group) names? I suspect that the actual user and group owner IDs are identical which, although not ideal because they're confusingly mapped to different names, allows seamless restoration of those back-ups.

Comment: Recall that `rsync` does not send _usernames_ to the recipient - it sends `UID`s. If, for example, on "Nextcloud server" the `www-data`  `UID` is `33`, while on "pi", `UID` `33` is assigned to `pi`, or unassigned. Do `getent passwd 33` (or whatever the `UID` is) on both systems.